# Long-run proportion that harmonic light bulb is on

Tags: sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers

Suppose a light bulb is turned on at time $t=0.$ It switches off at $t=1,$ on again at $t=1+{1 \over 2},$ off at $t=1+ {1 \over 2}+{1 \over 3},$ and so forth. As $t$ goes to $\infty,$ what proportion of the time is the light bulb on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole series is the alternating harmonic series, which in the limit as n approaches infinity equals $ln 2$.

As both individual series diverge, the difference goes to a 0 fraction in the limit, and the ratio approaches 1.0. Therefore the light is on half the time.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the first few terms of the series concerning the period of time the light is turned on and off:

$$\text{ON: }1, \frac 13, \frac 15,...\\ \text{OFF: } \frac 12,\frac 14, \frac 16,...$$

You can clearly see that the times you are looking for are:

$$\displaystyle\sum^{\infty}_{i=1} {\frac 1{2i-1}} $$

and

$$\displaystyle\sum^{\infty}_{i=1} {\frac 1{2i}} $$

Use harmonic series to solve

Comment: So....what proportion of the time is the light bulb on? Certainly this diverges.

Comment: The interesting thing is that the difference of the two series does converge, as the accepted answer points out.

Answer (score 1):

At any point in time, the light has been on longer than it has been off, as $1 > \frac{1}{2}$, $\frac{1}{3} > \frac{1}{4}$, etc. If we start looking at the light at $t = 1$, then at any point in time the light has been off longer than it has been on, as $\frac{1}{2} > \frac{1}{3}$, $\frac{1}{4} > \frac{1}{5}$, etc. So the proportion of the time that the light is on must be $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: That's spectacularly unconvincing.

Comment: How so? If we denote the proportion of the time that the light is on by $P$, then the first sentence implies $P \geq \frac{1}{2}$ and the second sentence implies $P \leq \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: It makes sense to me, but only after I understood Pieter's answer, which isn't that clear on first reading, either. But essentially Arthur is arguing the 1 at the beginning simply doesn't matter, and he is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The switches occur at the following time instants

$$\begin{aligned} t_0 &= 0\\ t_1 &= 1\\ t_2 &= 1 + \frac12\\ t_3 &= 1 + \frac12 + \frac13\\ & \quad \vdots\\ t_n &= \sum_{k=1}^n \frac1k =: h_n\end{aligned}$$

where $h_n$ is the $n$-th [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) (where $n \geq 1$). Just after the $n$-th switch, the total amount of time that the light bulb has been on is

$$g_n := \sum_{k=1}^n \left( \frac{1 + (-1)^{k-1}}{2} \right) \frac1k = \frac12 h_n + \frac12 \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k} $$

where, again, $n \geq 1$. Hence, after the $n$-th switch, the fraction of time that the light bulb has been on is

$$f_n := \frac{g_n}{h_n} = \frac12 \left( 1 + \frac{1}{h_n} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k} \right)$$

Since the [alternating harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Alternating_harmonic_series) converges,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k} = \ln (2)$$

whereas the [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)) diverges,

$$\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} h_n = \infty$$

we conclude

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n = \frac12 + \frac12 \underbrace{\left( \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{h_n} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k} \right)}_{= \frac{\ln (2)}{\infty} = 0} = \frac12 + 0 = \color{blue}{\frac12}$$

Comment: Integer sequences [A025547](https://oeis.org/A025547) and [A025550](https://oeis.org/A025550) may be of interest.